# Ford Figo Diesel - Cranking but fails to start

Tags: ford, diesel, cold-start, figo

I have ford Figo 2010 diesel model. When I try to start the car parked for 4-5days, it cranks but fails to start, then the car won't crank for another 5-10 min. The car cranks again after 10min if lucky the car starts, if not I have to repeat this cycle again after each failed attempt.
After the car starts then there is no issue. I could turn off and start the car again without any issues, it's the first start after 4-5days is the problem.

Also note that I could start the car by pushing it and engaging first gear when it fails to start after cranking. I also beleive its not a typical cold s

What could be the issue here.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I don't know if the Figo has a lift pump (pump to get fuel from the tank to the high pressure pump). If it does, it could be bleeding back into the tank after a long period of time. I'm wondering if you tried switching the ignition off/on several times prior to trying to start it if it might help the cold start. If it does, that's where I'd be looking.